# How do I sort a List<Map<String, dynamic>> by one of the map's values, descending?

Tags: flutter, dart, sorting

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> myList = [
                                   {'Field1': val1, 'Field2': 9, 'Timestamp': 11-01-23 12:00},
                                   {'Field1': val2, 'Field2': 8, 'Timestamp': 11-02-23 12:00},
                                   {'Field1': val3, 'Field2': 7, 'Timestamp': 11-03-23 12:00}
                                  ]
```

How do I sort this list by the Timestamp field descending in each map, such that:

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> sortedMyList = [
                                   {'Field1': val3, 'Field2': 7, 'Timestamp': 11-03-23 12:00},
                                   {'Field1': val2, 'Field2': 8, 'Timestamp': 11-02-23 12:00},
                                   {'Field1': val1, 'Field2': 9, 'Timestamp': 11-01-23 12:00}
                                  ]
```

Comment: Can you show actual dart data, instead of the pseudocode?  What is Timestamp there?  Is it strings, or DateTime?